# Alternate Answer for a probability fair dice game using conditional probability

Tags: probability, dice

**The problem:** In this game, if two dices give:
\begin{cases}
7 \text{ or } 3, \text{ then the player wins} \\
2,\space 11 \text{ or } 12, \text{ then the player loses} \\
\text{else, then the game continues with the following rule}
\end{cases}
New rule for tie, continue throwing the dices until the one of the following condition is met.
\begin{cases}
\text{the number from first round}, \text{ then the player wins} \\
7, \text{ then the player loses} \\
\end{cases}
Find the probability of winning.

**Attempt:** 
I thought the most straight forward way of doing this problem is find the conditional probability of each case after the tie. This gives $\frac {244}{495}$ as the probability of winning.

**Question:** The problem is that I know my professor loves using trick to solve problems. Thus there must be a faster way to do this. It actually took about a page to work this out.

Comment: Are you sure it's the number from the last round and not from the first round? Because that would make it equivalent to [craps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps).

Comment: @joriki Yes, you are right. It is from the first round. I worded it wrong.

Comment: Then you should be able to find loads of stuff on this by googling craps.

Comment: @joriki Yes. Still I would love to see if there is a faster way than the normal way of going about this problem (my attempt).

Comment: From the Wikipedia article, it seems that your answer is wrong -- they get $244/495$. That makes a lot more sense, too, since it should be quite close to $1/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it in wrong.

Comment: What is the problem with the straightforward approach? The answer suggests that there is no tricky one.

Comment: @zhoraster There is no problem with the straightforward approach; however, I would like to know if there is a faster way to do this problem.